# htaccess rewrite underscores to dashes for a specific directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I can successfully rewrite underscores to dashes with the following -- but I need the code to work ONLY for a certain directory, and I can't get that part to work.

WORKS:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2-$3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

DOES NOT WORK:

```
RewriteRule ^/media/entry/([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ /media/entry/$1-$2-$3 [E=unscors:Yes]
RewriteRule ^/media/entry/([^_]*)_(.*)$ /media/entry/$1-$2 [E=unscors:Yes]
RewriteCond %{ENV:unscors} ^Yes$
RewriteRule ^/media/entry/(.*)$ http://domain.com/media/entry/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The `RewriteRule` should probably not have a leading `/`. Try it as `RewriteRule ^media/entry/.........` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove all leading `/` from `RewriteRule` patterns all should work fine (as in the first two example which work).

The the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^media/entry/([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ /media/entry/$1-$2-$3 [E=unscors:Yes]
RewriteRule ^media/entry/([^_]*)_(.*)$ /media/entry/$1-$2 [E=unscors:Yes]
RewriteCond %{ENV:unscors} ^Yes$
RewriteRule ^media/entry/(.*)$ http://domain.com/media/entry/$1 [R=301,L]
```

There is also nice [online htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) which will help you out verify your configuration e.g.

[image: Online htaccess tester]

The tool has some limitations though i.e. currently does not have implemented certain features like `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` or `%{ENV:...}` but for simple rules it should be fine.

I hope that will help.